# Put only a single file in git submodule/repository

Tags: git, github

I have a particular file in a git source code repository that contains production settings/passwords. I would like to restrict this file so that only members of a production team can see it. However, I would like to keep it change controlled.

I thought about using a submodule in git, and then restricting access to the new repository. However, git seems to need an entire subdirectory for the submodule, and I only want to add a particular file. As a side-effect of how the development tools work, I cannot create a subdirectory for the config file.

Can anyone give me some guidance on if there's a way to create almost a merge point with another repository for these files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only way seems to be writing git hooks to encrypt the parts that you want to keep secret. Otherwise the git deals files in the repo level, not as single entities.

- check [This article on Repository Access Control](https://wincent.com/wiki/Git_repository_access_control) and [about update-paranoid hook](http://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git;a=blob;f=contrib/hooks/update-paranoid;hb=HEAD)