# How can I save my secret keys and password securely in my version control system?

Tags: python, django, git, version-control

I keep important settings like the hostnames and ports of development and production servers in my version control system. But I know that it's *bad practice* to keep *secrets* (like private keys and database passwords) in a VCS repository.

But passwords--like any other setting--seem like they should be versioned. So what *is* the proper way to keep passwords version controlled?

I imagine it would involve keeping the *secrets* in their own "secrets settings" file and having *that* file encrypted and version controlled. But what technologies? And how to do this properly? Is there a better way entirely to go about it?

---

I ask the question generally, but in my specific instance I would like to store secret keys and passwords for a *Django/Python* site using *git* and *github*.

Also, an *ideal* solution would do something magical when I push/pull with git--e.g., if the encrypted passwords file changes a script is run which asks for a password and decrypts it into place.

---

EDIT: For clarity, I *am* asking about where to store *production* secrets.

Comment: Actually front up some money to keep the whole repo private.

Comment: @JohnMee I actually already pay for a private repository, but the point remains--you shouldnt keep sensitive information in your repository.

Comment: I think a large part of the reason satisfying answers will be hard to get is that the old-fashioned plaintext password to connect to a database is a relic of a less hostile era. The proper answer is something like "your code shouldn't need a secret", but the systems you are accessing don't give you much choice.

Comment: Will you access this confidential data only from Python? Then I would recommend a special file object.

Comment: @user1320237 a special file object? What is that? Where can I find documentation?

Comment: **Why?** There's zilch value in version controlling passwords for external services. The principal value of version control is that you can inspect historic revisions of your application known to be in working order and _run them_. However, old passwords are useless to you. If they've been revoked, they won't ever work again.

Comment: @ColonelPanic what you say makes sense, but in that case, what do you recommend?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/205606/strategy-for-keeping-secret-info-such-as-api-keys-out-of-source-control

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Heroku pushes [the use of environment variables](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) for settings and secret keys:

> The traditional approach for handling such config vars is to put them under source - in a properties file of some sort. This is an error-prone process, and is especially complicated for open source apps which often have to maintain separate (and private) branches with app-specific configurations.
>
> A better solution is to use environment variables, and keep the keys out of the code. On a traditional host or working locally you can set environment vars in your bashrc. On Heroku, you use config vars.

With Foreman and `.env` files Heroku provide an enviable toolchain to export, import and synchronise environment variables.

---

Personally, I believe it's wrong to save secret keys alongside code. It's fundamentally inconsistent with source control, because the keys are for services *extrinsic to the the code*. The one boon would be that a developer can clone HEAD and run the application without any setup. However, suppose a developer checks out a historic revision of the code. Their copy will include last year's database password, so the application will fail against today's database.

With the Heroku method above, a developer can checkout last year's app, configure it with today's keys, and run it successfully against today's database.

Comment: This answer hasn't enough attention, but it most coincides with the linux way.

Comment: So if environment vars are set in your bashrc, and you're deploying a new server, then what creates the bashrc? Doesn't that just move the passwords out of your source code repo, and into your deployment config? (which is presumably also in the source code repo, or in a repo of its own?)

Comment: @JonathanHartley your .bashrc shouldn't be in the code repo for your Django app.

Comment: @SteveSP Agreed! I don't quite understand what you're getting at. Sorry to be dense.

Comment: @JonathanHartley Hm maybe I misunderstood your comment? It sounded like you were saying that the deployment config/.bashrc was in the source code repo.

Comment: Sorry, my comment is ambiguous, but that's because I am genuinely confused. I love the sound of this answer's point of view, but have never fully understood it. If I'm deploying to several different environments, each of which contains several hosts, and perhaps several types of hosts, then obviously I need to automate the creation of the .bashrc files that will exist on each host to set its environment variables. So is the answer saying I should have a *second* repo, separate from my source, which contains all the settings which will become environment variables in .bashrc on deployment?

Comment: @JonathanHartley I don't think you need to automate the creation of the .bashrc.  You could use some central wiki or README or something (which is not tracked in a VCS and that only company employees have access to) that contains these passwords and instructions on how to set them as environment variables.  Environment variables only need to be configured once so each developer would do this when they first set up their laptops (or the servers for staging/production).

Comment: They only need to be configured once PER machine you deploy to. If your deployment process is "spin up a new machine and test it's OK before redirecting traffic to it and then shoot the old one in the head", which IMHO is best practice, then you really do need to automate the creation of whatever sets the env vars.

Comment: @JonathanHartley I would say that if you want to automate deployment then you store passwords for the deployment within that system. They are nothing to do with the development repo. e.g. if using something like puppet, puppet is responsible for deploying the bashrc and the passwords are therefore managed within that.

Comment: Just thought I'd note that about a decade later I agree (as does the industry more broadly?) that saving secrets in VCS is "bad". So what do you do? Use some combination of environment variables, config files, and the secrets management helpers of your platform/infrastructure provider. Sadly difficult to be more specific since often the path of least resistance depends strongly on the environment you're running your app in. (I've switched the accepted answer to this response.)

Answer (score 102):

You're exactly right to want to encrypt your sensitive settings file while still maintaining the file in version control. As you mention, the best solution would be one in which Git will transparently encrypt certain sensitive files when you push them so that locally (i.e. on any machine which has your certificate) you can use the settings file, but Git or Dropbox or whoever is storing your files under VC does not have the ability to read the information in plaintext.

**Tutorial on Transparent Encryption/Decryption during Push/Pull**

This gist https://gist.github.com/873637 shows a tutorial on how to use the Git's smudge/clean filter driver with openssl to transparently encrypt pushed files. You just need to do some initial setup.

**Summary of How it Works**

You'll basically be creating a `.gitencrypt` folder containing 3 bash scripts,

```
clean_filter_openssl 
smudge_filter_openssl 
diff_filter_openssl
```

which are used by Git for decryption, encryption, and supporting Git diff. A master passphrase and salt (fixed!) is defined inside these scripts and you MUST ensure that .gitencrypt is never actually pushed.
Example `clean_filter_openssl` script:

```
#!/bin/bash

SALT_FIXED=<your-salt> # 24 or less hex characters
PASS_FIXED=<your-passphrase>

openssl enc -base64 -aes-256-ecb -S $SALT_FIXED -k $PASS_FIXED
```

Similar for `smudge_filter_open_ssl` and `diff_filter_oepnssl`. See Gist.

Your repo with sensitive information should have a .gitattribute file (unencrypted and included in repo) which references the .gitencrypt directory (which contains everything Git needs to encrypt/decrypt the project transparently) and which is present on your local machine.

`.gitattribute` contents:

```
* filter=openssl diff=openssl
[merge]
    renormalize = true
```

Finally, you will also need to add the following content to your `.git/config` file

```
[filter "openssl"]
    smudge = ~/.gitencrypt/smudge_filter_openssl
    clean = ~/.gitencrypt/clean_filter_openssl
[diff "openssl"]
    textconv = ~/.gitencrypt/diff_filter_openssl
```

Now, when you push the repository containing your sensitive information to a remote repository, the files will be transparently encrypted. When you pull from a local machine which has the .gitencrypt directory (containing your passphrase), the files will be transparently decrypted.

**Notes**

I should note that this tutorial does not describe a way to only encrypt your sensitive settings file. This will transparently encrypt the entire repository that is pushed to the remote VC host and decrypt the entire repository so it is entirely decrypted locally. To achieve the behavior you want, you could place sensitive files for one or many projects in one sensitive_settings_repo. You could investigate how this transparent encryption technique works with Git submodules http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules if you really need the sensitive files to be in the same repository.

The use of a fixed passphrase could theoretically lead to brute-force vulnerabilities if attackers had access to many encrypted repos/files. IMO, the probability of this is very low. As a note at the bottom of this tutorial mentions, not using a fixed passphrase will result in local versions of a repo on different machines always showing that changes have occurred with 'git status'.

Comment: Oh very interesting. This sounds *almost* exactly like what I want (except its encrypting the entire repository).

Comment: You could either keep all the sensitive setting files for multiple applications in one encrypted repository or add the encrypted repository with the sensitive settings to your project as a Git submodule as described here http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules .

Comment: Storing production passwords/settings in an (encrypted) submodules is not uncommon. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11207284/put-only-a-single-file-in-git-submodule-repository . It would even make it easier to manage settings across projects.

Comment: It might be worth checking https://github.com/AGWA/git-crypt for an updated solution. It has the advantage of allowing individual files to be encripted, and it claims to be "provably semantically secure". The author of the gist himself suggested that this tool is better, at https://github.com/shadowhand/git-encrypt .

Answer (score 17):

The cleanest way in my opinion is to use environment variables. You won't have to deal with *.dist* files for example, and the project state on the production environment would be the same as your local machine's.

I recommend reading [The Twelve-Factor App](http://www.12factor.net/config)'s config chapter, the others too if you're interested.

Comment: It seems like environment variables are a good way to run the application with the secret settings... but it still doesnt answer the question of where to *keep* those settings.

Comment: You should usually have a README file for each of your apps. In there, specify which environment variables should be set, and every time you deploy a project, just follow the steps and set each of them. 
You can also create a shell script with many `export MY_ENV_VAR=`, and when you deploy, just fill it with the right values and `source` it. 
If by *keep* you mean version the settings, you shouldn't be doing this in the first place.

Comment: Also, upvote for [The Twelve-Factor App](http://www.12factor.net/config)--really great stuff.

Comment: @Samy: And if you've automated deployment?

Comment: @JonathanHartley: Updating your production environment shouldn't change environment variables. If you want to update them, you should do it manually, whether you deploy a new version of your application or not.

Comment: I'm worried about the case of creating new server instances. This might be done automatically to scale for traffic, or for some shops, this is a routine part of deploying a new version of your application. Setting environment variables manually each time doesn't seem appropriate in these cases.

Comment: @JonathanHartley I'm not an expert in the subject but the most simple way I can think about is having a shell script that creates another script which will be used to set all the needed environment variables (in other servers) by one single execution.

Comment: @Samy: Right, that makes sense, and it's where my thoughts were headed too. But in that case, then the shell script is kept in a source code repo, right? So we're back where we started with the OP's problem.

Comment: @JonathanHartley: I don't believe it's a bad idea to version useful scripts. The generated script should be ignored though.

Comment: @Samy: Are we talking about a generated script? I missed that part. What generates it and when? Thanks for your patience.

Comment: @JonathanHartley: Two answers before this one, I was talking about a script that creates another one. :) No problem, glad to help.

Comment: @Samy I still don't understand how environment variables would be set.   The 12 factor app page doesn't make that clear either (unless you're on Heroku, which my current project is not.) Are we saying that a generating script needs to ask a central config store "I'm machine X, please give me my config data", and that responds with the values of environment variables that should be set. In that case, I don't *think* you need a generated script any more. I'm wildly speculating here, am I barking up the right tree?

Answer (score 10):

An option would be to put project-bound credentials into an encrypted container (TrueCrypt or Keepass) and push it.

*Update as answer from my comment below:*

Interesting question btw. I just found this: [github.com/shadowhand/git-encrypt](https://github.com/shadowhand/git-encrypt) which looks very promising for automatic encryption

Comment: It would be nice to have something which I could automate. Such that if my encrypted password file changes it automatically decrypts the new file.

Comment: Interesting question btw. I just found this: https://github.com/shadowhand/git-encrypt which looks very promising for automatic encryption.

Comment: Wow, great. The description of `git-encrypt` sounds like exactly what I'm looking for " When working with a remote git repository which is hosted on a third-party storage server, data confidentiality sometimes becomes a concern. This article walks you through the procedures of setting up git repositories for which your local working directories are as normal (un-encrypted) but the committed content is encrypted." (Of course, I only want a subset of my content encrypted...)

Comment: @schneck post your comment as an answer so that Chris could accept it - sounds like it's what he's looking for.

Answer (score 10):

I suggest using configuration files for that and to not version them.

You can however version examples of the files.

I don't see any problem of sharing development settings. By definition it should contain no valuable data.

Comment: But then where to store the canonical password records? It would make me nervous to have that data sitting only in a configuration file on a machine which might blow up some day.

Comment: @ChrisW. If the machine blows up, you don't necessarily need the password anymore... However, if you only have one copy of the data on your production machine, that should raise up a red flag.  But that doesn't mean it should be in VCS.  There should be RAID, full backups supplemented by incremental backups on magnetic and optical media.  A lot of corporations have a change control procedure which may dictate how and where to store passwords and other sensitive materials on paper as well.

Comment: @ChrisW I dont' want to be rough but it seems you don't tell us the truth and the passwords you want to store are not used in Development but in production. Isn't this true? Otherwise, why do you care for a development or test machine and development passwords? Nobody would do that.

Comment: BTW, at our company, all the development passwords are available on paper and on the intranet. Because they have no value. They're there because the software we develop needs authentication.

Comment: @tiktak, you are correct--my question is about what do with regard to production passwords. I dont particularly care about storing development passwords in A VCS in the clear. Sorry if I haven't made that clear enough.

Answer (score 9):

Since asking this question I have settled on a solution, which I use when developing small application with a small team of people.

[git-crypt](https://github.com/AGWA/git-crypt)

git-crypt uses GPG to transparently encrypt files when their names match certain patterns. For intance, if you add to your `.gitattributes` file...

```
*.secret.* filter=git-crypt diff=git-crypt
```

...then a file like `config.secret.json` will always be pushed to remote repos with encryption, but remain unencrypted on your local file system.

If I want to add a new GPG key (a person) to your repo which can decrypt the protected files then run `git-crypt add-gpg-user <gpg_user_key>`. This creates a new commit. The new user will be able to decrypt subsequent commits.

Answer (score 7):

[BlackBox](https://github.com/StackExchange/blackbox) was recently released by StackExchange and while I have yet to use it, it seems to exactly address the problems and support the features requested in this question.

From the description on https://github.com/StackExchange/blackbox:

> Safely store secrets in a VCS repo (i.e. Git or Mercurial). These
>   commands make it easy for you to GPG encrypt specific files in a repo
>   so they are "encrypted at rest" in your repository. However, the
>   scripts make it easy to decrypt them when you need to view or edit
>   them, and decrypt them for for use in production.

Answer (score 6):

> I ask the question generally, but in my specific instance I would like
>   to store secret keys and passwords for a Django/Python site using git
>   and github.

No, just don't, even if it's your private repo and you never intend to share it, don't.

You should create a local_settings.py put it on VCS ignore and in your settings.py do something like

```
from local_settings import DATABASES, SECRET_KEY
DATABASES = DATABASES

SECRET_KEY = SECRET_KEY
```

If your secrets settings are that versatile, I am eager to say you're doing something wrong

Comment: But i'll still need to keep track of those secrets *somewhere*. E.g., keypass or something along those lines, right?

Comment: Regulation and implementation of storing private data depends on the policy of the company the project's for. I highly doubt the project's source code is the proper place as any third party tester or programmer could see these

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT: I assume you want to keep track of your previous passwords versions - say, for a script that would prevent password reusing etc.**

I think GnuPG is the best way to go - it's already used in one git-related project (git-annex) to encrypt repository contents stored on cloud services. GnuPG (gnu pgp) provides a *very* strong key-based encryption.

1. You keep a key on your local machine.
2. You add 'mypassword' to ignored files.
3. On pre-commit hook you encrypt the mypassword file into the mypassword.gpg file tracked by git and add it to the commit.
4. On post-merge hook you just decrypt mypassword.gpg into mypassword.

Now if your 'mypassword' file did not change then encrypting it will result with same ciphertext and it won't be added to the index (no redundancy). Slightest modification of mypassword results in radically different ciphertext and mypassword.gpg in staging area differs a lot from the one in repository, thus will be added to the commit. Even if the attacker gets a hold of your gpg key he still needs to bruteforce the password. If the attacker gets an access to remote repository with ciphertext he can compare a bunch of ciphertexts, but their number won't be sufficient to give him any non-negligible advantage.

Later on you can use .gitattributes to provide an on-the-fly decryption for quit git diff of your password.

Also you can have separate keys for different types of passwords etc.

Answer (score 3):

Usually, i seperate password as a config file. and make them dist.

```
/yourapp
    main.py
    default.cfg.dist
```

And when i run `main.py`, put the real password in `default.cfg` that copied.

ps. when you work with git or hg. you can ignore `*.cfg` files to make `.gitignore` or `.hgignore`

Comment: .dist files are what I was talking about: examples of real configuration files. A good practice is that it should be possible to run the software only by renaming by removing the ".dist" extension (or better: copying), that is, you should be able to try software in seconds, without having to configure it during the whole day.

Answer (score 3):

**Provide a way to override the config**

This is the best way to manage a set of sane defaults for the config you checkin without requiring the config be complete, or contain things like hostnames and credentials.  There are a few ways to override default configs.

Environment variables (as others have already mentioned) are one way of doing it.

The best way is to look for an external config file that overrides the default config values.  This allows you to manage the external configs via a configuration management system like Chef, Puppet or Cfengine.  Configuration management is the standard answer for the management of configs separate from the codebase so you don't have to do a release to update the config on a single host or a group of hosts.

**FYI:** Encrypting creds is not always a best practice, especially in a place with limited resources.  It may be the case that encrypting creds will gain you no additional risk mitigation and simply add an unnecessary layer of complexity.  Make sure you do the proper analysis before making a decision.

Answer (score 2):

Encrypt the passwords file, using for example GPG. Add the keys on your local machine and on your server. Decrypt the file and put it outside your repo folders.

I use a passwords.conf, located in my homefolder. On every deploy this file gets updated.

Comment: Then the software needs to decrypt the password file.

Comment: Well, only when deploying the site the password get decrypted and written to a plain text password file

Answer (score 2):

No, private keys and passwords do not fall under revision control. There is no reason to  burden everyone with read access to your repository with knowing sensitive service credentials used in production, when most likely not all of them should have access to those services.

Starting with Django 1.4, your Django projects now ship with a `project.wsgi` module that defines the [`application` object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/) and it's a perfect place to start enforcing the use of a `project.local` settings module that contains site-specific configurations.

This settings module is ignored from revision control, but it's presence is required when running your project instance as a WSGI application, typical for production environments. This is how it should look like:

```
import os

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "project.local")

# This application object is used by the development server
# as well as any WSGI server configured to use this file.
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Now you can have a `local.py` module who's owner and group can be configured so that only authorized personnel and the Django processes can read the file's contents.

Answer (score 2):

If you need VCS for your secrets you should at least keep them in a second repository seperated from you actual code. So you can give your team members access to the source code repository and they won't see your credentials. Furthermore host this repository somewhere else (eg. on your own server with an encrypted filesystem, not on github) and for checking it out to the production system you could use something like [git-submodule](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules).

Answer (score 2):

This is what I do:

- Keep all secrets as env vars in $HOME/.secrets (go-r perms) that $HOME/.bashrc sources (this way if you open .bashrc in front of someone, they won't see the secrets)
- Configuration files are stored in VCS as templates, such as config.properties stored as config.properties.tmpl
- The template files contain a placeholder for the secret, such as:

  my.password=##MY_PASSWORD##
- On application deployment, script is ran that transforms the template file into the target file, replacing placeholders with values of environment variables, such as changing ##MY_PASSWORD## to the value of $MY_PASSWORD.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach could be to completely avoid saving secrets in version control systems and instead use a tool like [vault from hashicorp](https://www.vaultproject.io), a secret storage with key rolling and auditing, with an API and embedded encryption.

Answer (score 0):

You could use EncFS if your system provides that. Thus you could keep your encrypted data as a subfolder of your repository, while providing your application a decrypted view to the data mounted aside. As the encryption is transparent, no special operations are needed on pull or push.

It would however need to mount the EncFS folders, which could be done by your application based on an password stored elsewhere outside the versioned folders (eg. environment variables).