# How to encript or secure the keys while pushing to GIT?

Tags: spring, git, spring-boot, github, gitlab

I am using developing the application using Spring Boot, there are some secret keys has to be added to the files but while committing and pushing the file to Git it must not be visible to the public.

As those keys in the files need to be secure, how to provide the security or any encryption to those files??

Comment: First thing would be not pushing them to a public repo.

Comment: Don't put them in the files you're pushing to git, provide them via e.g. environment variables.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I save my secret keys and password securely in my version control system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11575398/how-can-i-save-my-secret-keys-and-password-securely-in-my-version-control-system)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, don't push these files to a public repo, or any repo where you think other developers on the team should not have access.

You can easily ensure these files don't somehow get committed by using a `.gitignore` file:

> gitignore - Specifies intentionally untracked files to ignore

See: [.gitignore documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)

Here is a collection of useful **.gitignore** configurations: [A collection of useful .gitignore templates](https://github.com/github/gitignore)

Rather than using encryption, it would be better to use a directory and repo structure as follows:

**Project directory:** All project files, no secrets.

**Secrets directory:** Secrets only.

**Project repo:** Public repository.

**Secrets repo:** Private repository giving access to trusted developers.

Then within your project you simply reference the necessary secrets in the **secrets directory**.

If you do decide to use GPG encryption (not recommended as then you have to remember not to by mistake push an un-encrypted file), you can use a basic symmetric cipher. On a Unix machine, install gpg and then use the following terminal command - it will request a password and generate an encrypted .gpg file.

> -c, --symmetric             encryption only with symmetric cipher

```
gpg -c secrets.txt
```

Comment: .gitignore will stop from pushing it to the repository.
But I want to push it to repository but that should be able to view by the masters or some particular persons . It must not be visible to the Git public.

Comment: You could use something like gpg to encrypt the file with a password - your "masters" would then need that password and have to decrypt it on the other side when running builds etc. If that works for you then you can do that. Alternatively keep a private repo with all secret keys from a separate directory to the project build, as well as the public project repo without any keys - that's what I'd recommend.

Comment: Can u please provide me an example related to this.

Comment: See above answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should save that keys as an environment variables.

How to store and retrieve that values will depend on the tools you used.
In your case, I think Spring framework can do really. 
Hope you get the logic and can find out how to achieve that in Spring or server that you used.

Comment: Can You provide me a example in spring

Comment: I agree this is a good option. He still has the issue of wanting to pass the keys encrypted in a repo - which really shouldn't be done, at least not in a public repo.