# Git commit of cordova package.json project with sensitive data

Tags: git, cordova, ionic-framework, package.json, sensitive-data

I'm working on a Ionic/Cordova project which some plugins that need sensitive data:

- cordova-background-geolocation ***require*** a license;
- cordova-plugin-googlemaps ***require*** api keys.

When adding those plugins to the project, they get saved in my ***config.xml*** and ***package.json***.

My problem is that I need to commit to Github those files but how can I do it without committing those sensitive data?

Anyone have a solution or suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: Use a .gitignore file and insert these files there?

Comment: Probably you could use a git encyption tool for those specific files, something like `git-crypt`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I save my secret keys and password securely in my version control system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11575398/how-can-i-save-my-secret-keys-and-password-securely-in-my-version-control-system)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6826682/7976758

Answer (score 0):

I keep these local changes in a branch that never gets pushed. My workflow looks like this (assuming `master` tracks a public branch `origin/master`):

```
git checkout -b private
// make local changes, such as plugging in license keys, passwords, etc.
git commit -am "DO NOT PUSH: local changes"
// tag here because later my cherry-pick starts here
git tag -f LOCAL
// now work on what you need to work on... and whenever I am ready, commit away
git commit -am "feature 1"
// keep hacking...
git commit -am "feature 2"

// When I get to a point where I want to push the series of commits I've got to the remote repo:

git checkout master
git cherry-pick LOCAL..private

git push origin master
git rebase master private
git tag -f LOCAL
// resume working...
```