# How to remove API key from Android project before git push

Tags: android, android-studio, github, gitlab, bitbucket

I wonder how to hide an API key and replace it with
let's say empty string

before pushing to Github or any source control.

for example, I've API keys like

```
object Constants {
    const val API_KEY= "GOOGLE_API_KEY"
}
```

how to remove the actual one and add random or empty string when pushing.

Comment: see https://gist.github.com/loftywaif002/f2ebe2024ad73d6a579285dcba250465

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I save my secret keys and password securely in my version control system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11575398/how-can-i-save-my-secret-keys-and-password-securely-in-my-version-control-system). Generally, keys should never be hard coded or committed to repository. You should retrieve them dynamically like from environment variables, use a secure vault service, or similar approach.

Comment: On the assumption you may have already added the keys, it is important to remove them from any older commits. I'd recommend the BFG repo cleaner to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Secret manager

Take a look at [secret manager](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager).

### Git hooks

A way to achieve this could be using [git hooks](https://githooks.com/).
On `pre-commit`, use (for example) `sed` to find and replace your API_KEY. You can even restore it in `post-commit`.

### Debug resources

Another way is to add the API_KEY to a resource file in the `debug` variant folder. Add that file to your `.gitignore` so you can use the API_KEY in your code, but will never be commited.